# Why are timezones with same offset from UTC are showing different times?

Tags: java, date, datetime

I bumped into this issue today. I have set my clock to UTC-6.00 (Central America) time zone. I am converting the Date "06/01/2015::12:00:00 AM" ("MM/dd/yyyy::hh:mm:ss a" format) to a java Date object. And then I am reconverting the date object to String. There is a slight twist in how I am doing this though. I am listing the re conversion steps below -

1. Calculate UTC offset from current time zone. (-21600000)
2. Get all available timezone ids for this offset. (All have same offset)
3. Select the first time zone id. (Will have same offset)
4. Set this as the timezone.
5. Convert the date to string format using Java's Simple Date Format.

I see that the time now rendered is "06/01/2015::01:00:00 AM"

My questions :

1. Since the timezone offset is same during the creation and during conversion I expect the same time to be shown. But what I see is different. Why is it so?
2. Imagine the re conversion to be happening in the server and the creation to be happening in the client. I need to render back the same date and time to the client. How do I do this?

Please help! Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT : Following is the code. Note that I have set my current timezone to Central America.**

```
public class TimeTest {

public static void main (String args[]) {

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy::hh:mm:ss a");
    String dateInString = "01/06/2015::12:00:00 AM";

    try {    
        Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
        System.out.println("Before conversion --> " + formatter.format(date));
        System.out.println("After conversion --> " + convertDateValueIntoString(date));


    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}

private static String convertDateValueIntoString(Date dateValue){
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy::hh:mm:ss a");       
    String date;
    int offset = TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset();
    if (offset == 0) {
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        date = dateFormat.format(dateValue);
    } else {        
        String TZ[] = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(offset);
        String timeZone = TZ[0];
        if (timeZone == null) {
            date = dateFormat.format(dateValue);
        } else {
            TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone);
            dateFormat.setTimeZone(tz);
            date = dateFormat.format(dateValue);
        }           
    }

    return date;
}
}
```

Comment: Rather than *describing* your code, please *show* your code, as a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. It will be much, much easier to help you that way. (We don't know what you mean by the first two steps, for example - two time zones can have the same UTC offset at *one* point in time, but differ at another point in time...)

Comment: @JonSkeet Sure will do. Just a minute...

Comment: `getAvailableIDs(offset)` returns timezones with the given **raw** offset. And the raw offset isn't affected by daylight saving adjustment.

Comment: I was thinking on that. In spain we change by daylight saving 2 times a year. Could it be the difference for all of them? Is it always an hour of difference?¿

Comment: @JBNizet, can you please answer the second question as well?

Comment: @coder don't store the raw offset of the client. Store its timezone. If the client and the server use the same timezone to format and parse dates, no problem. If one uses a time zone and the other uses another time zone (even with the same **raw** offset), then you'll have such differences.

Comment: @JBNizet I agree with you. I can do this to new date data. But I have old date data which have been stored as per client's local time. I now need to 
1. Render it back to the client as is. 
2. Write date data to a file. Client cannot make edits to the file. It can only issue a write request.

I have no TZ info stored in the DB. The client, while making a request to the server, sends its offset in the request. I use this offset to reconvert the time. And hence the issue. How do I rectify it for the above two use cases?

Comment: As I said: make the client send its timezone, not its raw offset.

Comment: @JBNizet, I am sending raw offset and DLS offset from the client. And in the server, I am checking for the first available TimeZone ID with the given raw offset and DSL offset. Do you see anything wrong in this? Your help here is much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, this is wrong. Daylight saving rules depend on the specific time zone. All timezones, even with the same offset, don't have the same DS rules (days of application, etc.).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78598/discussion-between-coder-and-jb-nizet).

Answer (score 5):

1. Why are the times different:

The difference appears to be in the handling of daylight savings time.  Playing around with setting my machine to different time zones and printing the TimeZone toString() I ended up with:

```
Initial: sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Tegucigalpa",offset=-21600000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=9,lastRule=null]
Result: sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Bahia_Banderas",offset=-21600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,...
```

Note that these two TimeZones have the same offset, but one uses daylight savings time and the other does not.  The offset is all your code is looking at to find an appropriate TimeZone but the date formatting also uses the daylight savings offset.

2. How do I handle this:

The way every project I've been on that used times did it was to have all internal representation of time be in UTC (or a similar concept).  I would have your client convert the time to UTC on input (before sending it to the server), have all server storage use UTC, then when times go back to the client have the client format to the default TimeZone only for output to the user.

That way all your internal times are consistent and all your displayed times are localized for the individual instance of the client, so a user in America/Tegucigalpa may get the time as 12:00 but the user in America/Bahia_Banderas would see 1:00.  Both are correct for the users those times would be displayed to.

Comment: I have another case to be handled here. What if the server needs to write the correct time to a file? Client has no role in making changes to the file. Only the server has full authority to create and edit the file. How do I reconvert the time to the client's time? The case right now is such that there are date data already stored in DB which are NOT AS PER UTC.

Comment: @coder: Well do you know the time zones of the values in the database? If not, they're somewhat meaningless already. It's not clear what these values are meant to represent - *sometimes* UTC isn't the right way forward, but it often is. It depends on what it's representing. You should quite possibly be storing the real time zone ID as well as the local value though - it's very rare that *just* the local value is the right thing to store.

Comment: @1337joe, your advice will be considered to avoid mistakes in the future! Thank you very much for your reply!

Answer (score 4):

The [Answer by 1337joe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30409970/642706) is correct. I'll add a few thoughts.

This Question has much confusion floating around.

## Time Zone = Offset + Rules/Anomalies/Adjustments

First, a time zone is more than an offset from UTC. A time zone is an offset *plus* a set of past, present, and future rules about Daylight Saving Time and other anomalies & adjustments.

So whenever possible, use a [named time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) rather than a mere offset. And certainly do not mix usage of offset-only with usage of time zones and expect sensible results. That seems to be the core problem in this Question.

So, dig deeper to discover the original intent of the programmers who devised your existing stored data. I suspect they did indeed have a particular time zone in mind rather than a mere offset.

## Use Proper Time Zone Names

There is no such time zone as "Central America".

As 1337Joe points out, offsets and time zones vary around Central America. For example, `America/Managua` is six hours behind UTC while `America/Panama` is five.

By the way, avoid the 3-4 letter codes for time zones such as "EST" as they are neither standardized nor unique. The one exception is `UTC` of course.

## Specify Your Expected/Desired Time Zone

When [a] you know your incoming data represents a particular time zone or offset, albeit implicitly, and [b] you desire a certain time zone to be applied, do not call on the default time zone. That is asking for trouble. The default time zone can vary by host OS setting on machine by machine. And both the host OS settings can be changed at any time by an admin person. Thirdly, the JVM’s current default time zone can be changed at any moment *during runtime* by a call to [`TimeZone.setDefault()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault-java.util.TimeZone-) by any code in any thread in any app in that same JVM.

So, instead of relying on the default time zone, specify the desired time zone.

## Use UTC For Logic & Storage

As 1337joe said, your business logic, data storage, data communication, and database should all be in UTC (almost always). Only apply adjustments to local time zones when expected by the user/consumer.

In comments, the author said their project is already saddled with existing stored data implicitly representing a certain time zone or offset.

## java.util.Date `toString`

The `toString` method on java.util.Date automatically applies the JVM’s current default time zone. This makes working with time zone adjustments tricky. One of many reasons to avoid using the java.util.Date/.Calendar & java.text.SimpleDateFormat classes.

## Use Better Date-Time Library

Use either the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in Java 8 and later ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)), or the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library (which inspired java.time).

### Joda-Time

Here is some example code in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

According to the author’s comments, the incoming string implicitly represents a date-time value for a certain known time zone. That time zone is not stated, so I'll arbitrarily use Panama time zone. In this first part, we parse a string while specifying the time zone to be used during parsing and assigned to the resulting object.

```
DateTimeZone zonePanama = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Panama" );
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "dd/MM/yyyy::hh:mm:ss a" );
String input = "06/01/2015::12:00:00 AM";
DateTime dateTimePanama = formatter.withZone( zonePanama ).parseDateTime( input );
System.out.println( "Input as string: " + input + " becomes object: " + dateTimePanama + " with time zone: " + dateTimePanama.getZone() );
```

Now let's adjust to UTC. Here this is for demonstration. In real code you would generally do any further work using this UTC value.

```
DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTimePanama.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtc: " + dateTimeUtc );
```

For output, our user/consumer expects a String representation in the same Panama time zone and in the same format as our input.

```
String output = formatter.print( dateTimeUtc.withZone( zonePanama ) );
System.out.println( "Output in special format: " + output );
```

When run.

```
Input as string: 06/01/2015::12:00:00 AM becomes object: 2015-01-06T00:00:00.000-05:00 with time zone: America/Panama
dateTimeUtc: 2015-01-06T05:00:00.000Z
Output in special format: 06/01/2015::12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: Just saw your answer as I submitted mine. I find it fascinating that two answers were written in parallel and they both are rather lengthy :-)

Comment: @Basil Bourque, Excellent write up with some insightful information. Thanks much!

Answer (score 3):

**For question #1:** The timezone offset may be the same for different timezones, but the DST may be used or not and this results in a difference.

**For question #2:**

For the future, you can only be safe about the time when you use UTC. (you can work around, if your time data is "recent" - see below)

For the past, you cannot reliably extract the correct time.

**General conversion advice:**

I worked on a project dealing with timezones and DST in a JDBC driver. There were problems storing time values and reading them back correctly. I worked /real hard/ trying to get a conversion right, so we could spare the larger works of switching to UTC. There is no correct conversion without UTC. ( /real hard/ : Think of Pulp Fiction where Jules says "I'm trying real hard to be the shepherd." :-) )

**Question #2 / Future:**

If your client cannot send UTC times (maybe because it is a third party system):

When your server receives time data (non UTC) from the client, which you know to be current within a few minutes (maybe somewhat longer), you could try to use your UTC time and match that to the client's time. Imagine your client sends "2015-06-01 15:45" and you know, it is now "2015-06-01 18:51 UTC", then you may interpret the client's time as "2015-06-01 18:45 UTC". If the time data sent by the client may be older than about an hour, this will fail in some cases.

Or in other words: Say your client records temperature values. If the data sent by the client is not older than a few minutes, you can match that to the UTC time. If your client records temperature of one day and sends you that at the end of the day, you cannot correctly match the time.

**Why will you not be able to make a fully(!) correct conversion?**

Assume the night when DST changes, so that the clock is changed from 03:00 back to 02:00. You have once 02:30 before the switch and another 02:30 after the switch. The first 02:30 has another UTC time than the second 02:30. So with UTC you are fine. But only with the "client local" 02:30, you will never be sure.

Back to the client data age: If your client sends data not older than a few minutes for 02:30 and then later another for the second 02:30, you can distinguish this on the server. If at 04:00 you get two records for 02:30, you cannot restore UTC any more.

**Question #2 / Past:**

Can you add a flag in the database so that new times which are transferred as UTC are marked "reliable" and the old values are not?

---

**The output and the source:**

The output from running the modified source on my system which has a TZ of "Europe/Berlin". Note that this has DST in use, but the first fetched TZ ("Algiers") has DST not in use.

```
formatter's TZ is sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Berlin",offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=143,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/Berlin,offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]]
internal date value = 1433109600000 as UTC = 31/05/2015::10:00:00 PM
Before conversion --> 01/06/2015::12:00:00 AM
Conversion: offset != 0, using TZ sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Africa/Algiers",offset=3600000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=35,lastRule=null]
After conversion --> 31/05/2015::11:00:00 PM

Setting UTC...

formatter's TZ is sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]
internal date value = 1433116800000 as UTC = 01/06/2015::12:00:00 AM
Before conversion --> 01/06/2015::12:00:00 AM
Conversion: offset != 0, using TZ sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Africa/Algiers",offset=3600000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=35,lastRule=null]
After conversion --> 01/06/2015::01:00:00 AM
```

The source code:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class TimeTest {
    static TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");

    public static void main (String args[]) {

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy::hh:mm:ss a");
        String dateInString = "01/06/2015::12:00:00 AM";
        SimpleDateFormat utcformatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy::hh:mm:ss a");
        utcformatter.setTimeZone(utc);

        try {    
            Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
            System.out.println("formatter's TZ is " + formatter.getTimeZone());
            System.out.println("internal date value = " +  date.getTime() + " as UTC = " + utcformatter.format(date));
            System.out.println("Before conversion --> " + formatter.format(date));
            System.out.println("After conversion --> " + convertDateValueIntoString(date));

            System.out.println("\nSetting UTC...\n");
            formatter.setTimeZone(utc);

            date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
            System.out.println("formatter's TZ is " + formatter.getTimeZone());
            System.out.println("internal date value = " +  date.getTime() + " as UTC = " + utcformatter.format(date));
            System.out.println("Before conversion --> " + formatter.format(date));
            System.out.println("After conversion --> " + convertDateValueIntoString(date));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }

    private static String convertDateValueIntoString(Date dateValue){
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy::hh:mm:ss a");       
        String date;
        int offset = TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset();
        if (offset == 0) {
            System.out.println("Conversion: offset == 0 -- setting UTC");
            dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            date = dateFormat.format(dateValue);
        } else {        
            String TZ[] = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(offset);
            String timeZone = TZ[0];
            if (timeZone == null) {
                System.out.println("Conversion: offset != 0, did not find TZ, tz of dateFormat is " + dateFormat.getTimeZone());
                date = dateFormat.format(dateValue);
            } else {
                TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone);
                System.out.println("Conversion: offset != 0, using TZ " + tz);
                dateFormat.setTimeZone(tz);
                date = dateFormat.format(dateValue);
            }           
        }

        return date;
    }
}
```

Comment: I got to learn new things on reading your post! Thank you so much!